# php.exe only reading file, not executing

Tags: php, powershell

EDIT: As the comment below by Bacon Bits suggests, I needed to save as UTF8

I'm trying to execute any php script in Powershell on windows 10.

Looks like it's eating the "<" of the script and then treating the file as a normal file.

sample php script:

```
<?php

echo "why?";

?>
```

Result of running script:

```
C:\php\php .\test.php
  ? p h p

 e c h o   " w h y ? " ;

 ? >
```

Version information:

```
C:\php\php -v
PHP 7.3.5 (cli) (built: May  1 2019 13:16:56) ( NTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.5, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

I was running the cgi version earlier with nginx and it seemed to work fine in that context.

Comment: Make sure you are saving the file as UTF-8 and not UTF-16.

Comment: have you tried c:\php\php.exe c:\whereveryourfileis\test.php ??

Comment: That did the trick, Bacon Bits, thank you.